# Debug a vlookup() with indirect() vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I used `vlookup()` function and `indirect()`. It works perfect in the worksheet as

```
=VLOOKUP(I$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!"&"A:B"),2,0).
```

However, once I put it into vba, it returns an error, saying

> Compile error:Expected: list separator or )

My VBA function code is like this:

```
Function Haha(title As Variant, sht As Variant)

    Haha= VLOOKUP(title,INDIRECT("'"&sht&"'!"&"A:B"),2,0)

End Function
```

Comment: The question's already been answered perfectly, so I would like to know why you're not using `sht As Worksheet`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just write formulas in VBA - they are not the same language. You can use this:

```
Function Haha(title As Variant, sht As Variant)

    Haha= Application.VLOOKUP(title,Sheets(sht).Range("A:B"),2,0)

End Function
```